# Automation mobile application using appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am trying to automate an android application using `Appium` and `Cucumber` with Java.I have written the code for a functionality and it is working fine. But some times while running the script, it throws an error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original err
or: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET (WARNING: The server did not provid
e any stacktrace information)
```

Source code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.intel.truevr.appautomation.core.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import java.util.List;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

public class C754L2D {
    Capabilities c = new Capabilities();
    MobileDriver driver =  c.getDefaultCapabilities();
    Wait wait = new Wait() {
        @Override
        public Object until(Function isTrue) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Given("^User taps the toggle button in the live 2D video playing screen$")
    public void user_taps_toggle_button() throws Exception {

        MobileElement allow = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"));
        allow.click();
        List<MobileElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("android:id/text1"));
        for(MobileElement ele :list) {
            String text = ele.getText();
            if(text.equals("Live")){
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        MobileElement panoramicButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.jackalopelite.simplecontainer:id/rl_select_2d"));
        panoramicButton.click();
        MobileElement Screen= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.className("android.view.View"));
        TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
        ta.tap(Screen, 531, 357).perform();
        MobileElement toggleButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.jackalopelite.simplecontainer:id/fab_player_switch_mode"));
        toggleButton.click();
    }
    @When("^Taps back button in the transition screen$")
    public void taps_back_button() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        MobileElement backButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.jackalopelite.simplecontainer:id/iv_cardboard_back"));
        backButton.click();

    }
    @Then("^The transition screen should dismiss and user should be navigated back to 2d live video playing screen$")
    public void dismiss_transition_screen() {

        try{
            MobileElement cameraAngleSelectionButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.jackalopelite.simplecontainer:id/rl_player_switch_camera_parent"));
            if(cameraAngleSelectionButton != null) {
                System.out.println("The transition screen is dismissed and user is navigated back to 2d live video playing screen");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("The transition screen is not dismissed and user is not navigated back to 2d live video playing screen");
        }
        //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

This error gets cleared and the script works fine when I close the emulator and open it again. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Read this [github thread](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9053) , It is related to same issue.

Comment: There is no solution in that thread

Answer (score 0):

Hey please then kill all simulator programmatically after executing testcase. Below code might help you.

```
/**
 * Stop Simulator
 */
public void stopSimulator() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall \"iOS Simulator\"");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall Simulator");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you are openning a specific simulator you can specify this in above code.

For android simulator please use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb emu kill");
```

Comment: I am using android emulator. Will the same cod work for it?

Comment: Please use th above and let me know your feedback